# ASP .Net MVC/WebApi with Angular 4/5 Visual Studio Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and looking for an Angular with Web Api 2.0 (or MVC with Web Api) Template but not able to find one. When I try to google I get only links to Asp .Net Core related topics, no mention of identical template for older versions of ASP .Net. By older I mean any other than Core.

[image]

When I try to change the version of .Net to .Net Framework I still see only .Net Core templates:
[image]

Only available ASP .Net versions are Core.
There exists a template for single page application but it does not create an angular application:
[image]

If to look online, there is a template for Angular2 though:
[image]

But:

- It is not an official microsoft template
- I will need to upgrade the Angular version
- It has no generated api controllers with authorization
- No OWIN support
- No file nesting for component files in solution explorer
- All links to documentation or git hub are broken and response with 404

It's a nice and in some cases usefull template but still a lot of thing that would be nice to have in a template I will need to do manually, basically from scratch. **Does there exist some powerful and rich template for Angular5 and Web Api 2.0 like there is for .NET Core?**

Comment: ASP.NET Core runs on .NET Framework too. The wizard you used is specific to ASP.NET Core - it's says so in the title. The options ASP.NET Core options you see refer to the web framework, *not* the runtime. The templates you selected will run on .NET Framework just fine

Comment: As for "official" the only official templates when talking about Angular would be those created by the Angular team. Not that it really matters - Angular is a Javascript framework. Everyone adds links to the appropriate Javascript packages and adds the appropriate grunt/bower/gulp tasks.

Comment: Answer is no. There is no *official* Angular and Web API 2 template. Is there a reason not to use ASP.NET Core?